# New Share, geo-localized statuses and API

Tags: facebook, api, geolocation

Is there a way to get the meta-data of statuses created through the new status update form that is being roll-out to every one since last week (the one where you can attach a location and a place to your post) ?

Right now the only info that gets through the APIs is the status message... which often does not make sense without the shared location :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to access this metadata (location info attached to a post added via the www.facebook.com interface) but where a user checks in from the mobile site or iphone app, this is treated the way it always was on the /checkins connection.

I'm not sure if there are plans to add this metadata to the API, but if it's added it'll either be announced on the roadmap at https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ or on the blog at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, I wonder.

It could be that FB is rethinking their API strategy considering location data and privacy issues it might cause. Something that Google and others are facing currently. Otherwise it should be very easy addition to their existing API's.